# One Class Classifier Training

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, libsvm, outliers

I'm working on a classification problem where I have data about only One Class, so I wanna classify between that "Target"class against all other possibilities which is the "Outlier" Class. Therefore, I intend to use a One Class Classifier or LibSVM classifier.  But question here is:

Do I need provide training data for "Outlier" class? If yes, is there any way to get around that as I only have data about the Target class.

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve this with samples only from the positive class is [density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation). You can either fit a parametric model to your data (for example, multi-variate normal) or use a Kernel Density estimator (a little bit like a one-class version of nearest neighbour, with a kernelised distance metric). Then, evaluate the probability of your new data under the learned model, and if it's sufficiently low, reject it as a member of the class.

Comment: How do we evaluate the kernel density estimator itself? Like what kernel is good and what bandwidths to set. (We do have have functions to calculate bandwidths, but do we know if they are the best suited?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
One Class Svm for novelty detection and you only have to train it on target class and it will classify your data to be similar or different from the trained class
You can read scikit documentation for One Class Svm [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

The point in a one-class classifer is that no data from the outlier class is available. All 1C algorithms are designed based on this assumption. A common situation where 1C-classifiers are used is in health prognostics of machines. In such cases it is common to only have data from the healthy class as collecting data from a faulty class is extremely expensive & hard to obtain accurately since it would require one to break equipment just to see how the sensors react.

Possible algorithms that excluding the 1C-SVM mentioned above are:

-neural network auto-encoders. In this case the reconstruction error can be used to quantify whether the input is no longer part of the one class. This can also be extended to Variantional autoencoders for accurate isolation of latent variables (unsupervised classification of the anomalies).

-neural network 1C-classifers.

-HELM-1C networks